# How to create method and used this method inside Akka runWith()

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

Akka Stream code:

```
Source.range(1, 100).map(i -> {
        return Stream.of(i*4).toList();
}).runWith(Sink.foreach(a ->System.out.println(a)), materializer);
```

I want to create a method say `printList()` and move the `runWith` code(`Sink.foreach(a ->System.out.println(a))`), so it should be like this `runWith(printList(), materializer)`

Comment: Which list you want to print? Also you want to place printList() instead of System.out.println(a)?

Comment: I want a method like printList() {Sink.foreach(a ->System.out.println(a))} and .runWith(printList(), materializer);. This printList() will print all the list element like, 4, 8, 12 and so on

Answer (score 2):

The `printList()` method would have to return a `Sink`, or a runnable graph / sink shape. I don’t understand what you’re trying to do here exactly, so I’ll break down some of the things that confuse me, and maybe that will help you work out better code:

1. `Source.range(1, 100)` is a good start and will output integers one at a time from 1 to 100.
2. The next step, `map(i -> Stream.of(i * 4).toList())` is where my confusion starts. This will return a `List<Integer>` with exactly *one* element: i x 4 (so 4, 8, 12, 16, Etc in succession). The same effect, without a List, can be achieved simply with `map(i -> i * 4)`... this will return each element of the upstream Source multiplied by four.
3. Now, the `runWith(Sink.foreach(a -> System.out.println(a)), mat)`... in the code as you have it, it will receive a List with one element in it, 100 times.

If you want to take a Source of 100 Integer elements and put them into a List, there’s a Sink operator that will do exactly that: `Sink.seq()`. However you’d have to be sure that the Source is actually finite otherwise you’ll never get to the end of the collection that this Sink operator creates.

Guessing at your purpose, I would expect you want something like:

```
Source.range(1, 100)
  .map(i -> i * 4)
  .runWith(
    Sink.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a)), 
    materializer);
```

This will print

```
4
8
12
16
20
 ...
400
```

Comment: Actually, I am new to Akka, Akka Stream, please provide complete code as you explain in above. Thanks